# Get the URL of a Page a Program Tries to Visit and Intercept It

Tags: url

I have a program on my computer that sometimes visits a web page. I would like to be able capture the URLs of every page the program visits, and selectively redirect them to a different page. How could I do this? For example, if the program visits `www.example.com/aWebPage.html`, and `www.example.com/anotherPage.html`, I want the program to still be able to access `www.example.com/aWebPage.html`, but I want all attempts by the program to access `www.example.com/anotherPage.html` to redirect to `www.stackoverflow.com`. The problem is that I do not know the actual URLs that the program loads, so I need a way to determine that. The computer on which I want to perform this task is running Windows 8.1 Pro x64.

Comment: Operating system? What is "the program"? Please be more specific; there's no way we can answer your current question with the lack of details.

Comment: Maybe you could try out [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). It seems to be made for such a task.

Comment: @slhck Sorry, I guess that would be helpful. OS is Windows 8.1 Pro x64 and the program is not publicly available, so knowing what the program is would not be helpful.

Comment: [HTTPNetworkSniffer](http://support.moonpoint.com/reviews/software/windows/network/web/HTTPNetworkSniffer/) from [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net) will provide a report on HTTP traffic. Concatenating the host name with the path will give you complete URLs. Unfortunately, that will show all traffic and won't associate access to URLs with a particular program, but, perhaps, it still may be of some use to you.

Comment: @GiantTree That seems to be what I needed, thanks!

Comment: @moonpoint HTTPNetworkSniffer also seems to fit what I need as far as connecting to the internet is concerned, but it does not offer anything in the way of rerouting traffic.